# Why are saving xml files very slow in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I try to save XML files such as XAML or ASPX or any other files that contains XML content, Visual Studio is stuck, this is very bad because I used to press Ctrl+S every ten letters a type!

How can I improve the speed at which Visual Studio 2010 saves files containing XML content?

Comment: http://richarddingwall.name/2009/08/24/does-your-visual-studio-run-slow/

Comment: A lot of the vs2008 features are also in 2010 afaik. See if anything helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to change your hard disk to an SSD (Solid State Drive) and put your code and OS on it, this will solve the problem!

Comment: Unless it's a very big xml file or the harddisk is extremely slow, it doesn't seem to be caused by a slow harddrive. Isn't it your RAM or CPU?